# How to build the GDB documentation from source?

Tags: gdb

I've downloaded the GDB source:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

now how do I generate the documentation from source as can be downloaded from: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/ ?

I'm especially interested in the HTML documentation, especially if it is possible to build a single page version of it.

I'm at GDB master f47998d69f8d290564c022b010e63d5886a1fd7d after `gdb-8.2-release`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd binutils-gdb/gdb
./configure
cd doc
make html MAKEINFO=makeinfo MAKEINFOFLAGS='--no-split'
ls *.html
```

This assumes that you have `makeinfo` installed; that should be something like `apt-get install texinfo` on debian-like systems.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it failed with `make: *** No rule to make target 'html'.  Stop.`.  Any clues? GDB master f47998d69f8d290564c022b010e63d5886a1fd7d
 Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Make sure you're in the doc directory and you had run `./configure` before.

Comment: Yes, I had done that, so you don't reproduce at that commit? `make html` on toplevel does run however, but is taking a while for some reason. Wonder if you don't have to run it on toplevel, and then maybe there is a way to select just gdb.

Comment: I've updated the answer from memory; I'll just try it myself it if I don't get it right this time ;-)

Comment: It works!!!!!!! The devs should put that on the website instead of the crappy one paragraph per page thing!!!!

Comment: I've asked a similar question for GCC at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493013/how-to-build-the-gcc-html-documentation-from-source-into-a-single-html-page

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
cd binutils-gdb
./configure
make html MAKEINFO=makeinfo MAKEINFOFLAGS='--no-split'
find . -name '*.html'
```

then it takes a while, but generates single page HTML docs for all Binutils projects, which is also convenient.

`-j $(nproc)` does not work unfortunately.

I found that GAS docs for example could not be easily built as GDB by themselves. If you try to:

```
cd gas
./configure
cd doc
make html
```

then it fails with:

```
as.texi:23: @include: could not find bfdver.texi
```

so there seems to be a BFD dependency.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.