# How to build the GCC HTML documentation from source into a single page?

Tags: gcc

I had asked a similar thing for GDB at: [How to build the GDB documentation from source?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477303/how-to-build-the-gdb-documentation-from-source) , and it changed my life, now I want the same for GCC!

I managed to build the docs on Ubuntu 16.04 and gcc 6.4.0 source tree (to match my host) with:

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure
make
host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc
make html
xdg-open HTML/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/index.html
```

But I could not make it put everything into a single page, I tried:

```
make html MAKEINFO=makeinfo MAKEINFOFLAGS='--no-split'
```

but it does not work as for binutils.

If I don't build GCC itself first, and do just `make html` directly, it fails with:

```
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... /data/git/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/data/git/gcc/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/
local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/data/git/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
Makefile:24442: recipe for target 'configure-target-libgomp' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libgomp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/data/git/gcc'
Makefile:1268: recipe for target 'do-html' failed
make: *** [do-html] Error 2
```

The problem is that the file:

```
host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc
```

does not exist, I wonder why it is needed since all I want is to build the docs.

I would like to obtain the docs available at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/ and hopefully other manuals listed at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ such as CPP manual, each of them as a single HTML page that I can Ctrl + F easily on.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc
cd gcc/gcc
./configure
make gcc-vers.texi
mkdir HTML
makeinfo --html --no-split -Idoc -Idoc/include -o HTML doc/gcc.texi
```

Same for `gccint.html`, `cpp.html`, etc. `gcc`'s makefiles ignore the `MAKEINFOFLAGS` variable.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for `gcc`. I couldn't get it to work for `libstdc++-v3` though, but it is already a big progress.

Comment: It seems that `libstdc++` docs aren't built from Texinfo at all, but from DocBook via `XSLT` which is a completely different problem. (probably installing `docbook-utils` and then using `docbook2html -u` should do it, but I haven't tried it).

Comment: This answer appears to be broken with gcc I just cloned from git: the `gcc-vers.texi` target does not exist, and `make html` in general seems to not have made any HTML gcc docs at all even after having built gcc prior

Comment: @YetAnotherUser that's because you ran those commands in the *top directory*, not in the `gcc` *subdirectory*, as I did in my answer (`cd /path/to/gcc-8.2.0/gcc`). I'll update it with the whole recipe, starting with cloning the repository from scratch ;-)